# Installing Magento CE 1.7: Error when installing database

Tags: php, magento

I got a strange error when installing a fresh Magento CE 1.7 on my development server. I'm already successfully running test-installs in versions 1.5, 1.6 and 1.6.1.

After unpacking the tar (permissions set correctly according to [the SSH install guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_magento_via_shell_ssh#installing_magento_with_the_full_download)) I'm running the installer. I filled in my mysql credentials and hit the continue button. Magento tries to run all the queries to install the fresh database but fails after a few seconds with the error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in /var/www/html/magento/1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Resource.php on line 133

I already wiped out the entire webroot and unpacked everything again, running the installer all over. But every time I get the same error.

What can I do?

Thanks, aeno

---

As a reference, the full error including call stack:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in /var/www/html/magento/1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Resource.php on line 133

Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0002  341476  {main}( )   ../index.php:0
2   0.0034  685872  Mage::run( '', 'store', ??? )   ../index.php:87
3   0.0128  1810524 Mage_Core_Model_App->run( array ('scope_code' => '', 'scope_type'     => 'store', 'options' => array ()) )  ../Mage.php:683
4   0.5342  4244156 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch( )  ../App.php:354
5   0.5386  4728048 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match( class     Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http { protected $_originalPathInfo = '/install/wizard/installDb/'; protected $_storeCode = NULL; protected $_requestString = '/install/wizard/installDb/'; protected $_rewritedPathInfo = NULL; protected $_requestedRouteName = NULL; protected $_routingInfo = array (); protected $_route = 'install'; protected $_directFrontNames = array ('api' => '', 'xmlconnect' => ''); protected $_controllerModule = 'Mage_Install'; protected $_isStraight = FALSE; protected $_beforeForwardInfo = array (); protected $_paramSources = array (0 => '_GET', 1 => '_POST'); protected $_requestUri = '/index.php/install/wizard/installDb/'; protected $_baseUrl = '/index.php'; protected $_basePath = ''; protected $_pathInfo = '/install/wizard/installDb/'; protected $_params = array (); protected $_rawBody = NULL; protected $_aliases = array (); protected $_dispatched = TRUE; protected $_module = 'install'; protected $_moduleKey = 'module'; protected $_controller = 'wizard'; protected $_controllerKey = 'controller'; protected $_action = 'installDb'; protected $_actionKey = 'action' } )   ../Front.php:176
6   0.5502  5886736 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch( 'installDb' ) ../Standard.php:250
7   0.5669  6692776 Mage_Install_WizardController->installDbAction( )   ../Action.php:419
8   0.6027  7141188 Mage_Install_Model_Installer->installDb( )  ../WizardController.php:344
9   0.6046  7362904 Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates( )  ../Installer.php:161
10  0.6052  7366236 Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates( ) ../Setup.php:235
11  0.6062  7421544 Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb( '1.6.0.2' ) ../Setup.php:327
12  0.6091  7421736 Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Resource->setDbVersion( 'core_setup', '1.6.0.2' )  ../Setup.php:423
```

Comment: As always, as soon as you ask a question you can answer it for yourself...
Somehow the user group of the /app/etc/ directory wasn't set correctly so the installer could not write the local.xml

Setting the right group and re-running the installer did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may occur if the installer doesn't have rights for write in `app/etc`

Answer (score 0):

Delete your var folder.

I had same problem, after deleting var folder, Magento installed smoothly..

Hope this helps you.